# Lengthy error when using 'pip install qmesh' despite requisites being installed

Tags: python, installation, module, pip, pypi

I am trying to install qmesh following the instructions found here:
https://qmesh-synoptic-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

i.e. `pip install qmesh`

I am getting a lengthy error, which I have tried to troubleshoot but I have not been successful.

I have installed gmsh and qgis. I have tried multiple times to solve the issue but cannot find any similar problems online with solutions.

My error is below:[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look: the exception happens at [setup.py line 111](https://bitbucket.org/qmesh-developers/qmesh/src/2b8dedeabca736f73d8b3990b614bad76101d8e3/setup.py#lines-111). The except clause catches all exceptions and logs `msg` defined at line 104. But what if an exception occurs between line 98 and 103 (inside `try` but before `msg` is defined)? Boom, the name `msg` is not defined but used.

This is a bug in qmesh' `setup.py`. Please report it to the authors.